# How to install php-solr extension on Centos 6.6

Tags: centos, php5

I'm trying to install and configure the **Moodle Global Search** through Apache Solr. To install Moodle 3.1, I have to add an additional repository (REMI) to replace php (3 I think) packages by php 5.6 and 7.0 (`php56w` and `php70w`), it's working fine.

I'm stopped in a dead lock when I try to install a Moodle required php extension (`php-pecl-solr.x86_64`) for his Solr search system, looking for this package and trying to install it, I get an error about version, REMI repository doesn't have php-pecl-solr for versions 5.6 and 7.

> ** Here I'm little bit lost about what I can do to install this package and finish configuration on Moodle.

Does anyone know how can I install this extension for php 5.6 (php56w) ?

Dependency conflit that I get from yum

```
yum install php-pecl-solr2
```

Error log here:

https://gist.github.com/carlosjrcabello/559a40246e53241fb291119793065320

**CentOS version:** 6.6 64 bits